# change transparent color into white in html2canvas

Tags: javascript, html, css, html2canvas

I am using javascript library [html2canvas](http://html2canvas.hertzen.com) to save the table of my project. It works fine but when I save the image it shows transparent background color for PNG and background color black for jpeg.
Here is what I did:

```
<script>
        window.onload = function(){
              html2canvas(document.getElementById("tablePng"),{
                    onrendered: function(canvas){
                    var img = canvas.toDataURL('image/jpeg');
                    $('#saveTable').attr('href',img);
                  }
              });
      };
</script>
```

Doing these above will save the images but the background colour will be black and when changing `var img = canvas.toDataURL('image/png');` the background will be transparent.
And adding background as In documentation says:

```
    <script>
        window.onload = function(){
              html2canvas(document.getElementById("tablePng"),{
                    background: "#fff",
                    onrendered: function(canvas){                     
                    var img = canvas.toDataURL('image/jpeg');
                    $('#saveTable').attr('href',img);
                  }
              });
      };
</script>
```

will change nothing... give transparent.

So how do I change the background ground color so that the images saved will be readable easily?

Comment: What kind of background color has your table element in the DOM? According to the [documentation](http://html2canvas.hertzen.com/documentation.html) background sets the "Canvas background color, if none is specified in DOM. Set undefined for transparent".

Comment: @nietonfir its while. I am using bootstrap table.<table id="tablePng" class="table" align="center"  >

Comment: And what happens if you don't call the function `onload()` but manually instead?

Comment: @nietonfir it won't work. Actually I made a link and when click on that link the download option will appear. When tried using manually I have to make another link to save a image.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

simply add css `background-color:#ffffff` to your table :)

hope this helps

Comment: what a silly mistake I have made... I was digging only through the html2canvas but my logic was wrong in the table css. Thank You @g-newa. :)

Comment: who would of thought the need to make the background white on the element rendering a black background...seems simple but was not the first thought to set my white background to white...