# How to use bootstrap with xhtml2pdf?

Tags: django, rendering, generate, xhtml2pdf

#### I need to render PDF files dynamically in a Django web app.

I understand there are 2 options :

1. Render an html template file then convert it to a PDF file.
   I used **xhtml2pdf** Python library. 
   The issue is that the template I want to use has bootstrap and it isn't supported by xhtml2pdf. Actually no javascript is supported and the generated PDFs are horrible. 
   I have to write the html / css myself which I don't want to. 
   How to solve this problem ? 
   Is there an alternative library ?
2. Convert a webpage into a PDF file directly

Answer (score -1):

I had that problem too. I solved this problem with html2canvas and jspdf.

Here's my code. And use it by modifying it to suit you.

```
// on click 
<script src="{% static '/js/html2canvas.min.js' %}"></script>
<script src="{% static '/js/jspdf.min.js' %}"></script>

<script>
const page = document.getElementById('element that you want to make pdf')

$('#{{save_btn_id}}').click(function () {
  html2canvas(page).then(async function (canvas) { 
    // convert canvas to image
    let imgData = canvas.toDataURL('image/png');

    let imgWidth = 190; // image width (mm)
    let pageHeight = imgWidth * 1.414; 
    let imgHeight = canvas.height * imgWidth / canvas.width;
    let heightLeft = imgHeight;
    let margin = 10; 
    let doc = new jsPDF('p', 'mm');
    let position = 0;

    doc.addImage(imgData, 'PNG', margin, position, imgWidth, imgHeight);
    heightLeft -= pageHeight;

    // if page > 1
    while (heightLeft >= 20) {
      position = heightLeft - imgHeight;
      doc.addPage();
      doc.addImage(imgData, 'PNG', margin, position, imgWidth, imgHeight);
      heightLeft -= pageHeight;
    }

    
    doc.save('{{file_name}}-{{docNum}}.pdf');
})
</script>
```

Comment: Okay, so you don't even use an html template ? And what exactly is a "page" ?

Comment: I use html template. this is the last code of html file.
and the "page" is the area you want to extract.
for example, you want to generate the whole.

    page = document.body;

if you want to generate one table.

    page = document.getElementById('table id');

Comment: It is better to refer to another answer. like this
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66519144/export-pdf-with-jspdf-and-html2canvas