# Changing html2canvas to accept display as none

Tags: javascript, html2canvas, jspdf

I am using [jsPDF](https://github.com/MrRio/jsPDF) which make use of [html2canvas](https://github.com/niklasvh/html2canvas). [Here](http://mrrio.github.io/jsPDF/) is an example of it.

Based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25842082/2137778) answer, I downloaded html2canvas and started using it locally to make this change as suggested,
because the option of setting the colour as other answers proposed didn't worked for me.

Also, I notice other requirement I have which is different of what html2canvas delivers by default. I need to be able generate a PDF file even if the display is set to `none`.

Note on the example I gave, the option `HTML Renderer (early stages)` works with display none, but implements a poor render. On the other hand, `addHTML()` which is what I am using now, renders the page as it is, but this implies to render only what is visible.

This is the default method of html2canvas to decide what to consider as Visible.

```
function isElementVisible(element) {
        return (getCSS(element, 'display') !== "none" &&
                getCSS(element, 'visibility') !== "hidden" &&
                !element.hasAttribute("data-html2canvas-ignore"));
}
```

I commented the line: `getCSS(element, 'visibility') !== "hidden"`, and it enabled me to create a PDF even if `visibility: hidden`. However the samething is not true for `display: none`, even if the method always return TRUE.

How to implement it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A node with `display: none` can't get a [DOMRect](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.getBoundingClientRect) calculated for it, as it does not have one within the DOM (as it is `display: none`).

If you want to render `display: none` content, you'll need to make the `display` of the node something else prior to rendering.

Starting with html2canvas 0.5.0, you can provide an `onclone` option to html2canvas which is a callback that returns the cloned `document` object, where you can go and modify the DOM as you see fit prior to rendering it, without affecting the original `document`.