# How to save img to user's local computer using HTML2canvas

Tags: html2canvas

I'm rendering a screenshot onclick with HTML2canvas .4.1 and want to save the image to user's local computer. How can this be accomplished? Please note that I'm a beginner, so actual code will be most helpful to me.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="html2canvas.js"></script>

<button id="save_image_locally">download img</button>

   <div id="imagesave">
      <img id='local_image' src='img1.jpg'>
   </div>

<script>

    $('#save_image_locally').click(function(){

            html2canvas($('#imagesave'), 
             {
                onrendered: function (canvas) {
                    var img = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
                    alert('This will currently open image in a new window called "data:". Instead I want to save to users local computer. Ideally as a jpg instead of png.');
                    window.open(img);
                }
             });
            });

</script>
```

Answer (score 65, accepted):

**NOTE: this answer is from 2015 and the library has been updated.

Check the answers below for alternate implementations.**

Try this (Note that it makes use of the download attribute. See [the caniuse support table](https://caniuse.com/#feat=download) for browsers that support the download attribute)

```
<script>

  $('#save_image_locally').click(function(){
    html2canvas($('#imagesave'), 
    {
      onrendered: function (canvas) {
        var a = document.createElement('a');
        // toDataURL defaults to png, so we need to request a jpeg, then convert for file download.
        a.href = canvas.toDataURL("image/jpeg").replace("image/jpeg", "image/octet-stream");
        a.download = 'somefilename.jpg';
        a.click();
      }
    });
  });

</script>
```

Comment: Oh, the toDataURL function also takes a second parameter for quality between 0 and 1 if you want to set the jpeg quality/filesize

Comment: Thanks @2pha. This worked for me. Much appreciated.

At first there was some extra space getting saved, beyond the border of the original image. I was able to fix by adding style to the div. 

For example, to save a 512x512 image I did this:
<div id="imagesave" style="max-width:512px;max-height:512px";>

Comment: Thanks for this. However, when I apply this, everything works but the background is black instead of white. Any idea on how to fix this?

Comment: @ArkoElsenaar add css `background-color:white` to your element. or look at other solutions here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14584946/how-to-make-transparent-color-white-instead-of-black-in-canvas

Comment: This is the perfect solution
you can change the jpg to png

`a.href = canvas.toDataURL("image/png").replace("image/png", "image/octet-stream");`

Comment: png is actually the default, So `toDataURL()` would actually return the same as `toDataURL("image/png")`. I just put it there to demonstrate that you could request a type. To get a jpg, you would do `toDataURL("image/jpeg")`

Answer (score 47):

## update 2018

Notice that in the new versions of **Html2Canvas** the ***onrendered*** option is [deprecated](https://github.com/niklasvh/html2canvas/issues/1290#issuecomment-349623281) and replaced with promises.

To be able to download the image to the user computer, you may use something like this:

---

#### Html

```
<html>
    <head></head>
    <body>
        <div id="boundary">
            <div class="content">
                <p>My content here</p>
            </div>
        </div>

        <button id="download">Download</button>
        
    </body>
</html>
```

---

#### Javascript

Based on [Krzysztof](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41168203/4325011) answer

```
document.getElementById("download").addEventListener("click", function() {
    
    html2canvas(document.querySelector('#boundary')).then(function(canvas) {

        saveAs(canvas.toDataURL(), 'file-name.png');
    });
});


function saveAs(uri, filename) {

    var link = document.createElement('a');

    if (typeof link.download === 'string') {

        link.href = uri;
        link.download = filename;

        //Firefox requires the link to be in the body
        document.body.appendChild(link);

        //simulate click
        link.click();

        //remove the link when done
        document.body.removeChild(link);

    } else {

        window.open(uri);

    }
}
```

---

#### Issue encountered

Indeed i was able to download the image, but it was **blank** ...the possible cause for this (at least in my case) was that the content wrapper (**id="#boundary"**) has no width or height defined, so specifying a **height** and a **width** to the **content wrapper** did the trick for me.

---

hope this helps

Comment: This worked fine for me in Chrome 68, FireFox 61 and Safari 11.1.

Comment: Replace "html2canvas(document.querySelector('#boundary'))" with "html2canvas(document.querySelector('#boundary'),{useCORS: true,allowTaint: true,})" if you have images.

Comment: Yes, the example is working fine but looks like it is not capturing the desired screenshots, It captures only a part of boddry.

Comment: Should be the new accepted answer.

Comment: This still works in 2021 with html2canvas v1.3.3.

Comment: HELO from 2023. This works.

Answer (score 7):

This is the latest code that convert to PNG.

```
      $("#btnSave2").click(function() {
        html2canvas($("#widget"), {
          onrendered: function(canvas) {
            saveAs(canvas.toDataURL(), 'canvas.png');
          }
        });
      });

      function saveAs(uri, filename) {
        var link = document.createElement('a');
        if (typeof link.download === 'string') {
          link.href = uri;
          link.download = filename;

          //Firefox requires the link to be in the body
          document.body.appendChild(link);

          //simulate click
          link.click();

          //remove the link when done
          document.body.removeChild(link);
        } else {
          window.open(uri);
        }
      }
```

Answer (score 7):

## 2022 Answer:

```
<html>
  <head>
      <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://html2canvas.hertzen.com/dist/html2canvas.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/FileSaver.js/2.0.0/FileSaver.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
  <div id="to_save" style="text-align: center; width:300px; height: 300px;"> 
What is Lorem Ipsum?

Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
</div>

  <button id="download"> Download </button>
    
  <script>
    $( "#download" ).on( "click", function() {
      html2canvas(document.querySelector("#to_save")).then(canvas => {
        canvas.toBlob(function(blob) {
          window.saveAs(blob, 'my_image.jpg');
        });
        });
    });
  </script>
 
  </body>
</html>
```

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/jmyd6zx0/)

[SRC](https://ourcodeworld.com/articles/read/415/how-to-create-a-screenshot-of-your-website-with-javascript-using-html2canvas)

Comment: result in console - `Uncaught TypeError: window.saveAs is not a function`

Comment: @provance It seems it requires this: https://github.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js/

Comment: Thanks mate Works as of Nov 2022. Need to add all the js files in order to make it work. Does it has any other options like png/pdf to save?

Answer (score 0):

```js
function saveAs(blob, fileName="pic") {
    const link = document.createElement('a');
    link.download = fileName
    link.href = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
    link.click();
    URL.revokeObjectURL(link.href);
}

Html2Canvas(element).then(canvas => {
    canvas.toBlob((blob)=> {
      saveAs(blob, fileName)
    })
})
```