# Save Canvas & Legend as image

Tags: jquery, html2canvas

I have an existing application that uses html canvas to generate a graph.  There is a legend that also needs to be saved when the graph is saved.  Currenlty, if I right click to save the image, only the graph is saved.

I came across Cavas2Image.js & html2canvas.js and have implemented both in my project.

I have wired up a button to save the image.  Currently, when clicked it created a download file, but it is just called download and there is no extension.  If I add extension .png it then works correctly.  I do not know why this is not done by Cavas2Image, which is the whole point of using that library.  I put breakpoints and it is hitting the method to add the .png extension.

Based on the [documentation](https://github.com/hongru/canvas2image) (or lack thereof) of canvas2image.js, I should be able to use the single method to save my canvas:

```
Canvas2Image.saveAsImage(canvas, null, null, "png");
```

Here is my full code block:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <div id="widget" class="canvas__container">
            <canvas id="lineChartCanvas" class="chart chart-line canvas__canvas" chart-data="data" chart-labels="labels" style="height: 300px; width: 95%;"
                    chart-legend="true" chart-series="series" chart-click="onClick"></canvas>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12 text-center">
        <input type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="btnSave" value="EXPORT CHART" />
    </div>
</div>
<script>                    
    $(function () {
        $("#btnSave").click(function () {
            html2canvas($("#widget"), {
                onrendered: function (canvas) {
                    theCanvas = canvas;
                    document.body.appendChild(canvas);

                    // Convert and download as image 
                    //Canvas2Image.saveAsPNG(canvas);
                    Canvas2Image.saveAsImage(canvas, null, null, "png");

                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

I am using the two javascript files listed above even though they are not shown here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31657234/3591300).

You can do it just with [html2canvas](http://html2canvas.hertzen.com/documentation.html).
I've modified your code based on the linked answer and it works now. Though, I am not quite sure if this is what you want. You can name the file whatever you want and save it as png (the fiddle is jpg).

Check it out, let me know if you need more help.

```
$("#btnSave").click(function () {
       canvasdiv = document.getElementById('lineChartCanvas');
       html2canvas(canvasdiv, 
          {
              onrendered: function (canvas) {
                var a = document.createElement('a');
                // toDataURL defaults to png, so we need to request a jpeg, then convert for file download.
                a.href = canvas.toDataURL("image/png").replace("image/jpeg", "image/octet-stream");
                a.download = 'somefilename.jpg';
                a.click();
              }
          });
 });
```

Here is the link to the [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jc8hjquv/)* sample.

*
 *fiddle is loaded with bootstrap*

Comment: Worked perfectly.  Thank you.