# Create a screenshot using html5 canvas and add movable elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, canvas, screenshot

I am interested in building a new functionality in which the user can print what he sees in the page (as screenshot). But first he has to customize the position of some elements (images).

I am trying to find a way to do this and I was thinking of html5 canvas. I have little experience on this and I wonder if what I am thinking is at all possible.

My idea is to take a screenshot of the corresponding element (in this case is a div element with a map). I save this screenshot in a canvas and on top of it I place some other images (legend of the map) which are movable. The user can drag and drop them on the canvas.

Do all these make sense? Can it be implemented or is science fiction?

Comment: Yes it makes sense. It is possible, but that would depend on who is attempting it. What is your actual question? please read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask)

Comment: @2pha which part is difficult to understand? Or you just want to make your point..

Comment: Making a point.

Comment: But, [this stack question and answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31656689/how-to-save-img-to-users-local-computer-using-html2canvas/31657234#31657234) may help you