# Is it possible to download entire shiny application, including reactive values and multiple tables and graphs, to a pdf or image in one click?

Tags: r, shinyapps

I have been trying to find a solution to this problem for quite some time. I tried appshot, but my tables and graphs show as blank.

Any help or recommendations would be very appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Can you please add some more detail about what you are trying to achieve? It sounds like you want to take a screen shot..?

Comment: Hey J.Con, I appreciate the reply. 

I'd like users to be able to download a static copy of the entire shiny app, with reactive values populated in tables and graphs, in order for them to share their results with others. Whether that be a pdf, image, etc.

I'd like to preserve the current format of the html output as well. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use [`html2canvas`](http://html2canvas.hertzen.com/) JavaScript library to take screenshots.

For creating the prompt for download, I referenced this post: [How to save img to user's local computer using HTML2canvas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31656689/how-to-save-img-to-users-local-computer-using-html2canvas)

And, to run arbitrary JavaScript, you need to load `shinyjs` library in R.

Please see the example app below:

```r
library(shiny)
library(shinyjs)
library(DT)
library(ggplot2)

ui <- fluidPage(
    tags$head(
        # include html2canvas library
        tags$script(src = "http://html2canvas.hertzen.com/dist/html2canvas.min.js"),
        # script for creating the prompt for download
        tags$script(
            "
            function saveAs(uri, filename) {

                var link = document.createElement('a');

                if (typeof link.download === 'string') {

                    link.href = uri;
                    link.download = filename;

                    //Firefox requires the link to be in the body
                    document.body.appendChild(link);

                    //simulate click
                    link.click();

                    //remove the link when done
                    document.body.removeChild(link);

                } else {

                    window.open(uri);

                }
            }
            "
        )
    ),
    useShinyjs(),
    actionButton("screenshot","Take Screenshot"),
    dataTableOutput("table"),
    plotOutput("plot")


)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
    observeEvent(input$screenshot,{
        shinyjs::runjs(
            'html2canvas(document.querySelector("body")).then(canvas => {
                saveAs(canvas.toDataURL(), "shinyapp.png");
           });'
        )
    })


    output$table <- renderDataTable(iris)

    output$plot <- renderPlot(ggplot(data = iris) + 
                                  geom_point(aes(x = Sepal.Length, y = Sepal.Width)))
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can now use a dedicated package for this called [shinyscreenshot](https://github.com/daattali/shinyscreenshot). It uses the html2canvas library under the hood, but makes it very easy to use - simply call `shinyscreenshot::screenshot()` whenever you want to take a picture, and it'll download a PNG.