# html2canvas to print modal area

Tags: javascript, html2canvas

I am using html2canvas to convert webpage as image script is working fine, but how can I download or print only modal area instead of the entire body

I have tried with below link but not got the success 
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/PBGaMP

```js
// html2canvas <- https://html2canvas.hertzen.com/dist/html2canvas.min.js

// code reference: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31656689/how-to-save-img-to-users-local-computer-using-html2canvas

setUpDownloadPageAsImage();

function setUpDownloadPageAsImage() {
document.getElementById("download-page-as-image").addEventListener("click", function() {
html2canvas(document.body).then(function(canvas) {
  console.log(canvas);
  simulateDownloadImageClick(canvas.toDataURL(), 'file-name.png');
});
});
}

function simulateDownloadImageClick(uri, filename) {
var link = document.createElement('a');
if (typeof link.download !== 'string') {
window.open(uri);
} else {
link.href = uri;
link.download = filename;
accountForFirefox(clickLink, link);
}
}

function clickLink(link) {
link.click();
}

function accountForFirefox(click) { // wrapper function
let link = arguments[1];
document.body.appendChild(link);
click(link);
document.body.removeChild(link);
}
```

```html
<div id="modal1" class="modal" >
  <div class="modal-content" style="background-color: green;">
    <h4 style="color: honeydew;">Modal Header</h4>
    <script> document.write(new Date().toLocaleDateString()); </script>
    <p>Google</p>
  </div>

  <div class="modal-footer">
<button id="download-page-as-image">Download</button>


    <a href="#!" class=" modal-action modal-close waves-effect waves-green btn-flat"><i class="material-icons">close</i></a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function sendData() {
  var modalButton = $('[data-target="#myModal2"]')[0];
  modalButton.click();
  var modal = $('#myModal2')[0];

  setTimeout(function() {
     document.getElementById('myModal2').style.display = 'none'; // you use your modal's style display to "none" before converting to canvas image and again back to style display: 'block' or if any.
    html2canvas(document.getElementById('capture'), {
      allowTaint: false,
      useCORS: true
    }).then(function(canvas) {
        downloadCanvas(document.getElementById('test'), canvas, 'test.png');
        modalButton.click();
    });
    document.getElementById('myModal2').style.display = 'block'; // changing modal's style back to normal after canvas image gets created
  }, 1000);
}

function openCity(evt, cityName) {
  var i, tabcontent, tablinks;
  tabcontent = document.getElementsByClassName("tabcontent");
  for (i = 0; i < tabcontent.length; i++) {
    tabcontent[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  tablinks = document.getElementsByClassName("tablinks");
  for (i = 0; i < tablinks.length; i++) {
    tablinks[i].className = tablinks[i].className.replace(" active", "");
  }
  document.getElementById(cityName).style.display = "block";
  evt.currentTarget.className += " active";
}

function downloadCanvas(link, canvas, filename) {
    link.href = canvas.toDataURL();
    link.download = filename;
    link.click();
}

document.getElementById("defaultOpen").click();
```

Bit ugly fix, but I hope it helps you as far i understood your issue posted here.